# How to get value from javascript file and update new value in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have javascript file that I read from my workspace
this is part of the javascript

```
 "/*!
 * ${copyright}
 */

 .......


           a.initLibrary({
                            a: "a",
                            b: "b",
                            cattr: ["val1","val2"],

            });
      ...
```

I want to add new value to cattr parameter

```
   var pattern = [\s\S]*?cattr\s*:\s*\[([\s\S]*?)\]/;
    var controlStr = oContent.match(pattern);
   var controlArr = controlStr[1].trim().replace(/"/g, "").split(",");
   var newInput = "val3"
  if ( controlArr[0] !== "" ){
        newInput += ",";
    }
    newInput += "\t";
    oContent = oContent.replace("cattr: [",newInput );
```

can I do it all with regular expression ? there is case the cattr could be empty without any value meaning

```
          cattr :[]
```

How I can do it with regular expression and not with strings logic?

Comment: sorry it is part of the javascript file in my local

Comment: You need to be much more clear about exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to add new parameter to the cattr attribute according to the user input meaning that I need to update cattr attribute with new string value in the first time the cattr could be empty cattr :[] and sometimes it could be with values cattr : [ "val1"]

Comment: What if it is empty as you described? `cattr: []` ... What would you want to perform?

Comment: if it is empty in the first time cattr : [] then after the logic it will be cattr:["val3"]

Comment: Okay, but what variable contains this JavaScript? Are you using JS to do the find and replace? Why not just add an element at run time? Is it possible that the letters `cattr` appear more than once in the JS? Please clarify *exactly* what you are trying to do, or we can't help you.

Comment: I am using JS to find and to replace and I want to do in better  way. How I can add element in runtime what do you mean ? the letter cattr could be only once

Comment: Are you running the JS? Or just parsing it?

Comment: parse it and also I need to add ',' if there are more then 1 element

Comment: could you explain the meaning of  if (!/(.*,){2,}/.test(result)) { 
  result = result.replace(',', ''); 
}

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking to work with pure regex. You can try this.

```js
let orig1 = `a.initLibrary({
                            a: "a",
                            b: "b",
                            cattr: ["val1","val2"],

            });`;
            
let orig2 = `a.initLibrary({
                            a: "a",
                            b: "b",
                            cattr: [],

            });`;            
            
const replaceFn = (match, capture1) => {
  let insertValue = "adsdas";
  if(capture1 === "]") return `cattr: ["${insertValue}"]`;
  return `cattr: ["${insertValue}",`;
}

let new1 = orig1.replace(/cattr:\s*\[\s*(\])?/, replaceFn);
let new2 = orig2.replace(/cattr:\s*\[\s*(\])?/, replaceFn);

console.log(new1);
console.log(new2);
```